# can omniauth facebook be sign in from sub domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I've face one problem when I want to allow user sign from sub domain. I have create FB app with "lvh.me:3000" and this working find when I sign in from that  url. But when I want to allow user sign from sub domain Ex "abc.lvh.me:3000" it have an error which I cannot sign in. And I do research on google I found one solution like this:
`ruby
<%= link_to "Sign with FB", user_omniauth_authorize_url(:facebook, subdomain: false), class: "btn btn-facebook" %>`

and It is work find but after sign in it did not redirect to "abc.lvh.me:3000" but it redirect to "lvh.mr:3000" in stead. so do you know how can I solve this problem?

Comment: How did you redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect back by using devise `after_sign_in_path_for`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
   # check here that request is come from sub domain 
   # if come from sub domain then redirect it otherwise redirect your root path
  end
end
```

Comment: in that code block how can I redirect_to the right url?

Comment: But how can I know where  should we redirect_to the sub domain where user sign?

Comment: use request.referer you can do anything as you want. Also you can check here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#M009387